# Angular 8 Upgrade schematic to be used for updating ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular8

I am going through the guide to upgrade angular project to Angular 8. As part of upgrading the project to angular 8, its been mentioned, that its mandatory now to specify when the ViewChild needs to be initialized using the static variable like,

```
 // query results available in ngOnInit
 @ViewChild('foo', {static: true}) foo: ElementRef;

 OR

 // query results available in ngAfterViewInit
 @ViewChild('foo', {static: false}) foo: ElementRef;
```

Are there any schematics that we can run to take care of this automatically or generic upgrade schematics will do the favor? 
There are more than 400+ component files in the project it will be an heck doing it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Note: This should by default migrate your existing application code to 8. If you find some files have not been migrated yet, then run the following command.

```
 ng update @angular/core --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only --force --allow-dirty
```

**For more options:** https://angular.io/cli/update

Answer (score 1):

https://update.angular.io/ has i guide howto upgrade from 7 to 8.

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

> ng update will update your queries automatically, but it will err on the side of making your queries static for compatibility

Using this guide updated my code as well as doing the actual upgrade.